# Grammar of Negative Verb + 限り

Tags: grammar, verbs

I would like help with how 限り is used with a negative verb:

> 奇跡でも起きない限り あり得ないわよね

Jisho.org translate it as "unless". But how would this translation make sense then:

Unless (限り) even if miracle does not occur (奇跡でも起きない), its unlikely you know (あり得ないわよね)

How can we make sense of 限り  with negative verbs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

～ない限り, the *full phrase together*, means 'unless'. 限り does not mean 'unless' on its own. The sentence you've given is literally 'As long as a miracle does not occur, it's impossible.'

Comment: How would でも be explained here  ?

Comment: @JapaneseLearner in this context でも is best understood as conveying “something like”.

Comment: @A.Ellett Thank you !